# Table component shows blank report for XML data source

Tags: xml, jasper-reports

I am facing issues while creating table component in report summary panel using **XML as data source**, the final report shows a mere **blank line** .

Below is my xml data source named **ProjectXML.xml**

```xml
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="testsuite1"/>
    <testsuite name="testsuite2"/>
    <testsuite name="testsuite3"/>
</testsuites>
```

Below is my *.jrxml* file named **report12.jrxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report12" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bb749013-793e-4a97-a43a-08d89a11ce20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#3300CC"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#3300CC"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#3300CC"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#3300CC"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="tableDataSet" uuid="44f57638-9650-43f7-9a45-b12c6144c112">
        <queryString language="xPath">
            <![CDATA[/testsuites/testsuite]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/testsuites/testsuite]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <summary>
        <band height="238" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="59f049a5-d77e-480c-a1ee-46987630290d" key="table" style="table" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="238"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataSet" uuid="6d3ecced-ba97-49c1-aec9-7f5903748fa5">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column uuid="ed4b1e17-dcec-4ed6-9f1f-efb543f240b7" width="90">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="e2772a76-f9da-4438-8aa3-78cee739bdaf" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="d496fc00-bab8-4b85-bb8d-c75c1cfc3dc4" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Below is the screen shot of the blank preview of the **report12.jrxml**

[image: report12 Preview]

Advanced thanks for any help on this to get the full table with **TestSuite** names .

Comment: @Michaël very sorry actually my earlier posts did solve my issues but I didn't know how to accept the answers...or its related importance...so missed selecting the check box...sorry for that.. now I went through the link given by Alex ...and came to know how to do that.. so accepted all the answers which helped me earlier... Thanks Alex and Michaël .

Comment: its very critical for me.. could some one please help on this...

Comment: @uday035 I was able to reproduce this "bug" (I think that it is) with *iReport 4.5.0 and 4.8.0*. It is a known problem - you can view [Table component and XML datasource](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/540959/table-component-and-xml-datasource) and [using table elements with xml datasource](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/534913/using-table-elements-xml-datasource) posts at http://community.jaspersoft.com. You can try to use the *Detail* band for getting the same result - it's work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a "hack" and not very nice method, but it is working.

You can add the main (report's) dataset and use it in the *Table* component.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport .. whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" ..>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="tbDS">
        <queryString language="xPath">
            <![CDATA[/testsuites/testsuite]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/testsuites/testsuite]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <summary>
        <band height="98" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="76" y="33" width="360" height="50"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tbDS">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/testsuites/testsuite")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

In this sample I've used `((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/testsuites/testsuite")` expression for setting Table's datasource.

The result will be:

[image: The resulted report via iReport preview]

---

The another way to get design you want - is to use the *Detail* band (without using *Table* component).

---

I think the situation you described detects the bug of a *JasperReports* engine.

I've found similar posts at http://community.jaspersoft.com site: [Table component and XML datasource](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/540959/table-component-and-xml-datasource) and [using table elements with xml datasource](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/534913/using-table-elements-xml-datasource)

Comment: Yes Alex , Your given xml worked like a charm ..after placing this <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/testsuites/testsuite")]]></dataSourceExpression> ....but if I put simply the default expression like <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression> then the summary band shows blank and  the detail band shows the table records leaving the first row ..

Comment: although for all these.. frequent compatibility difficulties faced keeping  XML as a data source for jasper report desgining I move to keeping MySQL as a background byparsing the xml values and keeping in the database in a suitable table format.. then using that database for report design.. it makes life lot easier..:) ..  Thanks a ton Alex.. for helping with this...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on IReport, select Edit table Datasource, on dropdown list over Connection / Datasource Expression select

Use datasource Expresion

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)
```

and it works from Java app

Comment: Could you format this a little better?  It's really confusing.